# can't display custom files when entered localhost into a web browser

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am trying to make a web app. It uses the MVC design with custom template pages. anyway when i enter localhost/project3 i get this:
[image: This is what I get for localhost/project3]

instead of a homepage.

The homepage just has a static paragraph saying congrats at the moment.

```
<html>
.
.
.
<p>congrats</p>
.
.
.
</html>
```

Comment: Is Apache properly configured to use whatever the name of your homepage is to be a default?

Comment: I think so. Can you explain to me more in depth just to make sure.

Comment: nvm i needed a .htaccess file is all